# php.ini mail server settings configured but error msg says otherwise

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send mail locally using a (non-local) mail server. I already set the necessary values to the `php.ini` file. Below are the settings:

```
SMTP = mail.[domain-name].com
smtp_port = 465 
sendmail_from = info@[domain-name].com
```

I also added this to the config:

```
auth_username = info@[domain-name].com
auth_password = [mailpassword]
```

With all these configuration, I still get this error message:

> "Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port
>   25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini...."

It's telling me that I haven't done any changes to `php.ini`. I wonder why? Is there another `php.ini` file I should edit? Or is there another file that I need to configure? Btw, I'm using `XAMPP v3.2.2`. Anyone getting the same problem?

Comment: Did you restart the webserver? (XAMPP in your case)

Comment: Its been a while since ive used xampp, But i feel like there is a php.ini in the apache2 folder which is used by webserver. and the php.ini in the php folder is only used by shell usage of php. what the location of you php.ini?

Comment: I have a php.ini in /etc/php/7.0/apache2.

Comment: php.ini settings = nightmare. Normally I resort to setting them explicitly (where possible - not all settings allow this) via `ini_set()`.

Comment: Jason Joslin - this is the location: xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: Ivar - restarted XAMPP, nothing happened :(

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I'm on Win7. I think "etc" directory only applies to LAMPP? I forgot.